# Why does the DRF return 403 on a retrieve request when my permissionclass for retrieve is set to IsAuthenticated?

Tags: https, django-rest-framework, http-headers

I'm working on a project involving the DRF. I overrid the get_permissions() method on a standart ModelViewset but the retrieve permission doesn't seem to function properly as i have it set to IsAuthenticated but if i make a retrieve request i get a 403 response.

This is what my View looks like:

```
class chartView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = chart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = chartSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'list'  or 'create' or 'update' or 'partial_update' or 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve' :
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

In my urls.py i just use the *Defaultrouter()* and registered the view like this:
 *router.register('charts', views.chartView)*

When I'm logged in as Admin the list action works fine by accessing: 
*myurl.com/api/charts*
The retrieve action also works fine by accessing: 
*myurl.com/api/charts/instance*
But when i log in as non-Admin and try to access: 
*myurl.com/api/charts/instance*
 
I get a 403 forbidden response, which shouldn't happen since i set the permission class for the retrieve action to IsAuthenticated.

I've tried the following in my settings.py file: 
**a:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
   ),
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
   ),
}
```

**b:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
      'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
       ),
}
```

Comment: 1. Please, make sure you correctly format your code. 2. what's the response content ? 403 may have several reasons such as CSRF issues

Comment: You should not use the `or` operation like that. Your expression is equivalent to `self.action == True` since `True` will be the logical operation result of that part. Instead, you can use `self.action in ('list', 'create', ...)` to satisfy your requirement

Comment: @Linovia what is wrong with the formatting of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in `get_permissions()` you have such an expression

```py
if self.action == 'list'  or 'create' or 'update' or 'partial_update' or 'destroy':
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

What it actually did is firstly process the `or` operations between those string, and the result is intuitively `True`. Thus only when the value of `self.action` is not `False` or other values equivalent to `False` will make this expression failed, yet this will also not occur here since `self.action` will be the value of your action method name. That is, this expression is always `True` and thus results in your `permission_classes` to be always `IsAdminUser`

Instead of doing so, you can write like this:

```py
if self.action in ('list', 'create', 'update', 'partial_update', 'destroy'):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```